# How to fix this URL error in Wordpress " data-wplink-url-error="true">

Tags: plugin-development

This URL error is being added to the front of all of my links in Wordpress:
" data-wplink-url-error="true">
Another question on this forum answered why it is happening, but did not address how to fix it. Everytime I remove the link and add it back in, the error comes back.  Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?
Using latest version of wordpress, Block Lite theme.  Just trying to insert Amazon links into text.
Thanks.